# .NET Web Service - How to call unmanaged C dll

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, asmx

I have a requirement to call a dll (unmanaged c) from a .NET web service (asmx or WCF).

Calling the dll from the web service is straightforward and works as expected.

However, issues emerge when I load test the web service. (error code 0xC0000374 - "an internal error, typically involving heap corruption”).

I've been informed by the owner of the dll that the dll isn't reliable in a multi-threaded environment if 2 or more calls are sent at the same time.

In a traditional windows app, I'd deal with this by implementing a singleton class to protect the dll. Is there a recommended approach for achieving this in a web service implementation?

Comment: please, try to share **as much** details as possible. "issues emerge" - what kind of issues?

Comment: I don't really see how singleton pattern protects from parallel calls coming from different threads.

Comment: Andrey, question updated with more info.

Comment: please can you explain how did you call a dll from .NET web service asmx ? 
i need to achieve the same but it seems like i can't load dll.

Comment: @JohnC can you please provide a sample of calling a dll from Web service ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to ensure that only one thread at a time can call your dll, you can wrap any access to it in `lock` statements:

```
public static class MyDllCalls
{
    private static object _lockObject = new object();

    public static int SomeCall()
    {
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            return CallSomeFunctionInYourDll();
        }
    }
}
```

Only one thread can hold the lock at a given time, so this way you can prevent several threads from making calls in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent from multiple threads calling the same method in parallel you could use a [locking mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(VS.71).aspx).